# Python has stopped working (APPCRASH) in Windows, using GDAL to read and update shapefiles

Tags: python, windows, multiprocessing, gdal, shapefile

I have a complex program, made up of a number of Python scripts, which uses GDAL to open Esri shapefiles, performs various calculations, and updates shapefile attribute tables.

For some shapefiles it works absolutely fine. For others, Python crashes with the following Windows dump:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: python.exe
  Application Version:  3.6.2150.1013
  Application Timestamp:    5970e8c6
  Fault Module Name:    StackHash_234c
  Fault Module Version: 6.3.9600.18969
  Fault Module Timestamp:   5aa29ff0
  Exception Code:   c0000374
  Exception Offset: PCH_23_FROM_ntdll+0x0000000000090D0A
  OS Version:   6.3.9600.2.0.0.16.7
  Locale ID:    2057
  Additional Information 1: 234c
  Additional Information 2: 234c4b9abb92dbbbd5d8715a2bb9ade8
  Additional Information 3: e275
  Additional Information 4: e275aeecddf3edab35389c7521a4e7f7
```

I've tried some debugging and the crash appears unrelated to any particular line of code - instead it seem to occur after around 3.5 seconds, although this time can vary slightly.

The code does create a number of subprocesses for multiprocessing, running an asynchronous log queue, etc.

I'm running the program remotely on a Windows server that has 512GB RAM and 56 processors (28 cores).

I realise that this is nowhere near enough information to solve my crashing issue - I'm looking for some advice on how to go about debugging this problem, as I'm not used handling errors at the OS/system level. Any advice would be appreciated, and if anyone is willing to help I can gather whatever additional information you need.

Thanks!

Comment: What does the python stacktrace show when it crashes, does it even throw stacktrace? How are you running this script remotely?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't throw a stacktrace - that's what's making this so tricky! I'm using a remote desktop connection to the server, and launching the script with a windows .bat file. Having done a bit of digging, "Exception Code: c0000374" relates to a STATUS_HEAP_CORRUPTION - A heap has been corrupted. I don't really know what this means but it sounds like a memory issue, but obviously with Python I'm not getting into manual memory allocation. Maybe it could be a hardware issue?

Comment: Remember that GDAL in python is a wrapper of the GDAL implementation in C... so in C you *do* allocate memory and perhaps the error is tracing back to a native method of some sort...